# Parentheses in output

Tags: python, output, parentheses

I can't get rid of the parentheses in my output. I've already changed the default version of python in Visual Studio Code from 2.7 to 3.9. I also changed one of the print commands to a return command. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
def build_car(year, color, make, model, *car_accessories): 
    print(f"This car is a {year} {color} {make} {model}  with the following accessories--:") 
    for accessory in car_accessories: 
        return (f"{car_accessories}")

car = build_car('2021', 'tan' ,'ford','focus',
                'leather seats',
                'tinted windows',
                'all wheel drive') 
print(car)
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?  Python is white space sensitive, and all of your def's and for loops look on the same level.

Comment: you are returning an array. So the parenthesis will stay unless you want to print(*car)

Comment: Please fix your indentation, currently it will fail with indent errors.

Comment: Include an example of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Change the return statement - those brackets are specifying that the return value is a tuple. Use `return f”{car_accessories}”` or in this case much more simply `return car_accessories`

Comment: @barny - if the goal is to print the accessories, returning is not the right answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the best way to enter the code here so it would be readable, but in the original code, the lines are indented.

Comment: @AndyLeeParker - The code needed some manual formatting to make the code block look right. You can change it again if my edit isn't right.

Comment: Who knows what the goal is, the ‘code’ is not a [mre].

Comment: You need to decide what role `build_car` plays in your code. Should it build a printable string (then don't `print` in it)? Should it do the print (then don't print its return value)?

Comment: I would like it to look like this: This car is a 2012 tan ford focus with the following accessories:  leather seats, tinted windows, all wheel drive

Comment: Edit your question with the example - don't put it in the comments.

Comment: @barny - OP had problems with stackoverflow's markdown, but after fixing the indentations it is an MRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `*car_accessories` is a tuple and when you print that tuple, it formats with the surrounding parentheses. You could always use something like the following to convert a tuple to string. Once you have the string, you can apply whatever formatting you want with the f-string.

```py
return ', '.join(car_accessories)
```

Comment: The print isn’t needed to convert the tuple to a string and in fact all it does is _print_ the string.

Comment: @barny - considering that the code just printed other stuff, printing may be exactly what OP wants.

Comment: Its not clear exactly what code this example replaces. Can you make this a full example of the fix to OP's code?

Comment: You’re guessing - and your statement “something like the following to convert a tuple to a string” is not what your code does - your code prints a string.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo. It should have been a return statement replacing the OPs return statement. Woops. I edited my comment.

And I definitely am guessing at the OPs intention here since the goal of the function in unclear. I believe that the concern in the question lies in the printed output.

Comment: bdempe, your suggestion to use return ','.join(car_accessories) worked! Now I just have to study further to understand how and why.  Many thanks to everyone who took the time to respond, even though I didn't post the code correctly.

Comment: This answer is helpful (+1) as it explains where the parentheses are coming from, i.e., the arguments `*car_accessories` are wrapped up in a `tuple`. Adding a link to the docs may make the answer even better, see 4.7.4. Arbitrary Argument Lists in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html.

Comment: Andy P, if you edit your post to clarify what are want and what you are confused about we can certainly provide you with resources to learn more.

Comment: @Troy's suggestion below also worked--and it displayed the output in a vertical list!  The only down side was that it also printed None at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the info that tuples format with surrounding parentheses!

Answer (score 1):

`build_car` can't make up its mind. Its printing some stuff, returning other stuff for the caller to print. Very confusing. The function is more general purpose if its role is just to format the string. Let the caller decide what to do with it next. Since `car_accessories` is a tuple of items, you can "join" them with a comma. And the entire formatting step can be done with a single f-string.

```
def build_car(year, color, make, model, *car_accessories):     
    return f"""This car is a {year} {color} {make} {model} with the following accessories:
{", ".join(car_accessories)}
"""

car = build_car('2021', 'tan' ,'ford','focus',
                'leather seats',
                'tinted windows',
                'all wheel drive')
print(car)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build the entire description within the function and return that completed product.  Splitting the printing between the function and calling program is awkward.

```
def build_car(year, color, make, model, *car_accessories): 
    description = f"This car is a {year} {color} {make} {model}  with the following accessories: "
    description += ' '.join(car_accessories)
    return description

car = build_car('2021', 'tan' ,'ford','focus',
                'leather seats',
                'tinted windows',
                'all wheel drive') 
print(car)
```

Output:

```
This car is a 2021 tan ford focus  with the following accessories: leather seats tinted windows all wheel drive
```

Your original code also has a problem in that it `return`s as soon as it hits the first accessory.  Please review how `return` works, so you don't make this error again.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience and giving me a specific topic that it would be helpful to learn more about.  .